# terminal - blank the prompt

Tags: command-line

Let's say I've typed something into the terminal:

```
Joeterm$egrep " [1-9] " resultsAugmented.txt | egrep -o "20..-..-.." | sort | uniq| grep -c 2010
```

…but I've not pressed enter yet - I suddenly rememeber that I can't run the command until I first do something else - what are the fastest ways to

1. blank the prompt without executing the command (I mean, I could leave something heavy on backspace and go and make a cup of tea, but that's not all that efficient)?
2. Save the command I've typed for later recall, before I then do 1.

I'm looking for least keystrokes ideally…

Comment: I would simply open another terminal window/tab, honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, the default `stty kill` key, works pretty much everywhere in Unix terminals.

In *bash*, it will also put the deleted text in the "kill ring", to be inserted later with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>. This does not persist between sessions, however.

Answer (score 3):

`<Ctrl-a>#<Enter>` to go to beginning of the line, comment it and "run" it. It will be saved in your shell's history.